# How to index github repo in google? (Not a github pages)

Tags: github, boilerplate, repo

I got Apollo GraphQL Express boilerplate

https://github.com/aryawpratama/apollographql-boilerplate

And I want to make my repo is indexed by google as well as this repo

https://github.com/hagopj13/node-express-boilerplate

will appear on search result when you search "express boilerplate" in google

How to do that? Thanks in advance